# Deadlock in SQL Server in simple update operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL command like this:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET ColA = @ColA, ColB = @ColB, ColC = @ColC
WHERE ID = @ID
```

which is executed as the sole command in its own transaction. Multiple of these transactions are executed simultaneously from across multiple program threads (presumably regarding different IDs), and in under some unknown circumstances, I get deadlocks:

> Error: Transaction (Process ID 372) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>   Statement: UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID

The queries are run on about fifty different installations/environments, these deadlocks only occur on a few select machines.

I have found a post on MSDN that this [can be caused by a missing index](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dba45618-1d64-4661-891d-74cab09dddf1/deadlock-while-running-multiple-update-statements?forum=sqldatabaseengine), however, the `ID` column is the primary key. Do I have to add another index on that column, and if so, which type of index would work?

EDIT: This is the content of an xml_deadlock_report retrieved from Management -> Extended Events -> System_Health -> package0.event_file:

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process3b6651c38" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process3b6651c38" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 45:1:12951 " waittime="3873" ownerId="35041102" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.700" XDES="0x3bf35dd40" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="6972" status="suspended" spid="306" sbid="0" ecid="3" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.700" lastbatchcompleted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.700" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.700" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WSERVER01" hostpid="1984" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="35041102" currentdb="45" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="66" sqlhandle="0x02000000b14fad3a90dbdc90c36b1078cbce60ffaeefea220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@ID nvarchar(152),@ColA int, @ColB int, ColC varchar(30))UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process3b2d22188" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 45:1:42575 " waittime="3874" ownerId="35041102" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.700" XDES="0x27dd93c50" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="7572" status="suspended" spid="306" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.700" lastbatchcompleted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.700" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.700" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WSERVER01" hostpid="1984" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="35041102" currentdb="45" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="66" sqlhandle="0x02000000b14fad3a90dbdc90c36b1078cbce60ffaeefea220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@ID nvarchar(152),@ColA int, @ColB int, ColC varchar(30))UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process3b2d250c8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="3611" schedulerid="3" kpid="1496" status="suspended" spid="317" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" lastbatchcompleted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.673" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WSERVER01" hostpid="1984" loginname="dbUser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="35041090" currentdb="45" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="66" sqlhandle="0x02000000b14fad3a90dbdc90c36b1078cbce60ffaeefea220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@ID nvarchar(152),@ColA int, @ColB int, ColC varchar(30))UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process3b2d24cf8" taskpriority="0" logused="19872" waitresource="PAGE: 45:1:42575 " waittime="3782" ownerId="35041090" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" XDES="0x3bf361d40" lockMode="U" schedulerid="3" kpid="2600" status="suspended" spid="317" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" lastbatchcompleted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.673" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WSERVER01" hostpid="1984" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="35041090" currentdb="45" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="66" sqlhandle="0x02000000b14fad3a90dbdc90c36b1078cbce60ffaeefea220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@ID nvarchar(152),@ColA int, @ColB int, ColC varchar(30))UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process3b6657498" taskpriority="0" logused="19872" waitresource="PAGE: 45:1:12951 " waittime="3780" ownerId="35041090" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" XDES="0x3acb75760" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="2748" status="suspended" spid="317" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" lastbatchcompleted="2018-03-28T09:34:11.673" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.673" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WSERVER01" hostpid="1984" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="35041090" currentdb="45" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="66" sqlhandle="0x02000000b14fad3a90dbdc90c36b1078cbce60ffaeefea220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@ID nvarchar(152),@ColA int, @ColB int, ColC varchar(30))UPDATE tableName SET ColA=@ColA, ColB=@ColB, ColC=@ColC WHERE ID=@ID   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12951" dbid="45" subresource="FULL" objectname="dbName.dbo.tableName" id="lock266e05c00" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594041663488">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process3b2d250c8" mode="U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process3b6651c38" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="42575" dbid="45" subresource="FULL" objectname="dbName.dbo.tableName" id="lock2668a9280" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594041663488">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process3b6657498" mode="U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process3b2d22188" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <exchangeEvent id="Pipe32a7fe700" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="2">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process3b6657498" />
    <owner id="process3b2d24cf8" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process3b2d250c8" />
   </waiter-list>
  </exchangeEvent>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="42575" dbid="45" subresource="FULL" objectname="dbName.dbo.tableName" id="lock2668a9280" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594041663488">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process3b2d22188" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process3b2d24cf8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12951" dbid="45" subresource="FULL" objectname="dbName.dbo.tableName" id="lock266e05c00" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594041663488">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process3b6651c38" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process3b6657498" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

What can I read from this?

Comment: this might help: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/07/difficulty-deadlocks/

Comment: What else are you running in the same transaction? Where do you call that query from? If you run a SELECT to find rows to update in the same transaction, eg from an ORM using the transaction-per-request *anti*pattern, the rows already have shared locks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not running anything in the same transaction. A new transaction is made for this statement only.

Comment: Are you sure that "tableName" is only table? Are per row updates enabled?

Comment: @przemo_li I am sure that "tableName" is a table and no other table is part of the statement, explicit or implicit (no triggers etc.). How can I check whether per-row updates are enabled? If this setting can be changed for the whole SQL server, this may be the issue since it only happens on certain environments (= a few select SQL servers out of dozens).

Comment: @Alexander they always are. If there are deadlocks, it means the queries locked more than they should. When a deadlock occurs a lot of information is stored in SQL Server's log. A deadlock graph is also generated if you use SQL Server Profiler or Extended events. Check [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx) for more info

Comment: Ideally, you want to obtain a deadlock graph to see what the statement is deadlocking with, and how (even if it's deadlocking with itself, which at this point is speculation). See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31280.finding-and-extracting-deadlock-information-using-extended-events.aspx) for how to pluck it from the system health trace (you can also set up more permanent monitoring using event notifications, if the event is rare and you don't have time to babysit the trace).

Comment: @Alexander [this article by Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/extended-events-doesnt-hard/) shows how to configure Extended Events to capture deadlock graphs. You can [configure a collection process just for deadlocks](https://www.sqlshack.com/automate-sql-server-deadlock-collection-process-using-extended-events-sql-server-agent/)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I will do, but perhaps you can enlighten me on something in the meantime: If I am not mistaken, for a deadlock to be possible, every participating process has to lock at least two resources. Which two resources would these be in that update statement? As far as I see, only a single resource has to be locked, the one row (found through Primary Key index) that should be updated.

Comment: The locking happening during an `UPDATE` is more involved than you think. In particular, locks may be row locks, page locks and schema locks, and updates first take intent locks when searching for the row(s), then upgrade these locks to exclusive once the row is found to do the actual update, then take *more* locks if indexes are to be updated. Meanwhile, other queries can take range locks... Deadlock traces are essential to find out what's going on; in my experience, speculating on what's happening and "trying stuff" almost never helps fix deadlocks permanently (but they *are* fixable!)

Comment: @Alexander if you want to understand what happened you need the deadlock graph. If you want to prevent it anyway, use snapshot isolation. It was added to ease lock contention for such scenarios

Comment: @Alexander, a likely reason for a deadlock here is either there are indexes on the updated columns so updates from different threads may have to update the same indexes. Another possibility is multiple statements in the same transaction. The deadlock graph will reveal the root cause.

Comment: I have a xml_deadlock_report XML file retrieved from Management -> Extended Events -> System_Health -> package0.event_file, is this what you mean by "Deadlock Graph" or does the admin of the affected org have to run SQL Profiler for a few hours?

Comment: The presence of an `e_waitPipeGetRow` is peculiar. This normally means a parallel plan is involved, but this query seems just like the sort of query that should get a trivial sequential plan when proper indexes are present. Check the execution plan (and [paste it](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like Lock escalation is taking place - even though you are only updating 1 row SQL will pessimistically lock the page or even the table.

One option that worth trying is to use the WITH ROWLOCK hint on your update.
In theory this will apply the locking only on the affect row.

Comment: Shouldn't that be insufficient for a deadlock? If A locks a and nothing else, after it finish, it release that, so no dead locks. If A do not lock a, but wait for B to release it, A do not block B as long as A have nothing else locked.

Comment: well from the XML above we can see that process process3b6651c38 has page 12951 locked and is waiting on page 42575 - Process process3b2d22188 has page 42575 locked and is waiting on page 12951 - So the cause of the deadlock is clear. as to why multiple pages are being locked? (hmm) perhaps there are secondary indexes on the tables that are impacted by the update statement - I'd be interested in seeing what object id 72057594041663488 resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

After many many problems with deadlocks, I struggled to isolate them to a specific issue, but did find a way to resolve them in 99.99% of the instances we had.
We had 1 table that was frequently accessed by 1000s of users. We found deadlock errors were occurring roughly once in about 100,000 UPDATE queries, but this was enough to cause significant headaches and customer complaints.

The solution: Define a simple TRY/CATCH function to try multiple times before giving up

```
Function ExecuteSQL_TryCatch ( DB_Object , 
    SQL , 
   MaxAtempts, 
   DelayBetweenAtempts , 
   ErrorsCaughtWrite )

  AttemptCounter = 0 
  AttemptSuccess = "no"

  While AttemptCounter < MaxAtempts 

   try {
     DB_Object.Execute SQL
     AttemptSuccess = "yes"
   } 

   catch {
    Pause ( DelayBetweenAtempts )
   }

   AttemptCounter += 1

   If AttemptSuccess = "yes" Then
     // Exit the while loop
   End If 

  Wend

End Function

//THIS IS THE QUERY

SQL = "UPDATE tblCalendarEntries SET calendarEntryDetails = 'this is a happy day' WHERE calendarEntryID = 101 "

ExecuteSQL_TryCatch ( DBCON ,  SQL ,  5 , 2 , "yes" )
```

This solution obviously does not fit all circumstances / errors and you may wish to qualify the nature of the error before deciding to retry, but for us this fixed everything.